# Straightedge-only construction of a perpendicular

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, contest-math

> There is a circle in the plane with a drawn diameter. Given a point
>   inside the circle (not on the diameter or the circle), draw the
>   perpendicular from the point to the diameter using only a
>   straightedge.

**Source:** [This question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/481000/some-old-russian-problems) It is about to be closed for containing too many problems in one question. I'm posting each problem separately.

Comment: A construction for this is as follows: draw lines from the endpoints $E_1$ and $E_2$ of the circle through the point (call it $A$), meeting the circle in $B$ and $C$; now extend $E_2C$ and $E_1B$ until they meet in $D$, and draw $DA$ for the perpendicular. I have no *proof* of this, however.

Comment: The proof can be found in the field of Projective Geometry. I don't remember the proof either, but I vividly remember this construction from my projective geometry classes.

Comment: I can't sketch it out right now, but some right triangles should show up. Maybe use similarity?

Comment: @user1296727: You're right on the money. The proof is simple: The altitudes of $\triangle DE_1E_2$ are concurrent; $E_1B$ and $E_2B$ are altitudes meeting at $A$. Therefore, $DA$ is perpendicular to $E_1E_2$. Please post it all as a solution.

Comment: @TedShifrin Per my comment below (in case it didn't ping you), thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Solution: Taking it as known that the [perpendicular bisectors of a triangle are concurrent](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/geometry/triangle-properties/perpendicular_bisectors/v/circumcenter-of-a-triangle), and that [this implies the concurrence of the altitudes of a triangle](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/geometry/triangle-properties/altitudes/v/proof---triangle-altitudes-are-concurrent--orthocenter), our construction and proof are simple.

Draw lines from the endpoints $E_1$ and $E_2$ of the circle through the point (call it $A$), meeting the circle in $B$ and $C$; now extend $E_1C$ and $E_2B$ until they meet in  $D$. Now, by Thales' theorem, $E_1B$ and $E_2C$ are altitudes of $\triangle E_1DE_2$, meeting in the point $A$. Thus, the third altitude of this triangle, dropped from $D$, also passes through $A$; that is, $DA$ is the third altitude of the triangle. As such, it is perpendicular to the diameter of the circle. 
[image]

Comment: And thanks to @TedShifrin for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: I've fixed a couple of typos and added an image to help with the understanding; feel free to remove it if you don't like it.