# Construction using a straight edge only

Tags: geometry, circles, geometric-construction

> **Given a circle, its diameter and a point on the circle, find a procedure to construct a line perpendicular to the diameter using only a straight edge. The perpendicular must pass through the given point.**
>
> [image]

I can do this if [another point outside the circle is given,](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/481019/straightedge-only-construction-of-a-perpendicular) but my question is the degenerate case when that point lies on the circle.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: If you're not allowed simply to pick an arbitrary point somewhere, you won't be able to do anything -- once you've drawn AX and BX, every two intersection points on your diagram are already connected by a straight line. But note that, at least in the rules given by the top answer to the question you link to, marking an arbitrary new point _is_ an allowed operation.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Sorry, I forgot to add that the perpendicular must pass through the given point. I have added it now. Can you please give some insight to this question?

Comment: @HenningMakholm I have posted the [second part of the question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1762811/straight-edge-only-geometric-construction). Would you mind helping me out? Thanks.

Comment: @SubhadeepDey I saw this sometime ago in an old russian book. Anyway, the link you provided doesn't answer my current questions.

Comment: @SubhadeepDey "This question" which you are referring to is actually tagged in my question also. The link to the solutions which you provided doesn't answer my questions. It says  "Nonetheless even in these
cases it is possible to draw a perpendicular through X to line AB using only a straightedge. It is a challenge to you to find a suitable procedure!"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Here's a solution**

[image]

Let $C_1 \not \in \omega$.

$H -$ orthocenter of $\triangle AC_1B$

1) $C_1H \perp AB$

2) $C_1H \cap \omega =\left\{D,E\right\}$

3) $DX \cap AB=P$

4) $PE\cap \omega = F$

5) $FX \perp AB$

> **Explanation for $(5)$ :** Let the centre of the circle be $O$. Note that $\Delta ODP$ and $\Delta OEP$ are congruent, $\implies \angle ODP = \angle OEP$. Now, $\Delta DXO$ and $\Delta EFO$ are isosceles and congruent, so $\angle PXO = \angle PFO$ , and therefore $\Delta XPO$ and $\Delta FPO$ are congruent by SAA. If we mark the intersection point of $DE$ and $AB$ as $Z$, by the above deductions, we have that $\Delta XPZ$ and $\Delta FPZ$ are congruent, thus $\angle XZP = \angle FZP = 90^{\circ}$

The above explanation is due to Mr. Henning Makholm.

Comment: Can you please explain why $FX \perp AB $ ?

Comment: $X$ and $F$ are symmetric with to $AB$

Comment: I can see that $D$ and $E$ are symmetric w.r.t. the circle (by congruent triangles), but to prove that $X$ and $F$ are symmetric, we will need to have $FX \perp AB$ which is what needs to be proved.

Comment: Your reasoning seems circular to me.

Comment: $X$ is entering a point $F$ with respect to the symmetry line $AB$

Comment: I can see that, but it lacks rigour. Can you point some congruent/similar triangles which can support your claim?

Comment: $S_{AB}(PD)=PE$ and $PD\cap \omega =X$ and $PE\cap \omega =F \Rightarrow S_{AB}(X)=F$

Comment: What do you mean by $S_{AB}(PD)=PE$ ?

Comment: $S_{AB}(F_1)=F \equiv $ $F_1$ and $F$ symmetric with respect to a straight line $AB$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39010/discussion-between-henry-and-roman83).

Comment: @Henry: Call the center of the circle $O$. You seem to accept that angles $DPO$ and $EPO$ are equal. But then triangles $XPO$ and $FPO$ are congruent (by SSA, which is not normally valid, but the _other_ solution below the diagonal would be $EPO$ and we've explicitly chosen $F$ to be _different from_ $E$). Thus $XFP$ is isosceles and $AB$ is its angle bisector.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Perfect! Can this be added to the original solution if the author doesn't mind?

Comment: @Henry I don't mind

Comment: (Possibly a less handwavy argument than SSA would be that DXO and EFO are isosceles and congruent, so angles PXO and PFO are equal, and therefore triangles XPO and FPO are congruent by SAA).

Comment: @HenningMakholm I have another doubt. SSA states that two different triangles can be constructed given two sides and an angle not included. Considering the points $X$, $D$, $E$ and $F$ we'll get $4$ different triangles, out of which I can prove $2$ to be congruent (i.e, $\Delta ODP$ and $\Delta OEP$). However, I don't see why would the other two be congruent?

Comment: @Henry: See comment immediately above yours.

Comment: @HenningMakholm That's epic! Thanks a ton!

Comment: @HenningMakholm I have edited the answer. Can you approve it?

Comment: 1) $C_1 \in AX$; 2)$C_1B \cap \omega= Y$. Then $\angle AXB=\angle AYB =90^{\circ}$. 3) $AY \cap BX=H - $ orthocenter

Comment: @BarryCipra: This problem is very simple

Answer (score 2):

"how does it construct the orthocenter H using only a straightedge?"

1) $Z \in AX$;

2)$ZB \cap \omega= Y$.

Then $\angle AXB=\angle AYB =90^{\circ}$.

3) Let $AY \cap BX=H - $ orthocenter $\triangle AZB$

[image]

Comment: I have posted the [second part of the question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1762811/straight-edge-only-geometric-construction). Would you mind helping me out? Thanks.