# Straight Edge - Only Geometric Construction

Tags: geometry, circles, geometric-construction

> **Given a circle, its diameter and a given point on the diameter, find a procedure to construct a line perpendicular to the diameter using only a straight edge. The perpendicular must pass through the given point.**
>
> [image]

This question is a follow up to my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1762456/construction-using-a-straight-edge-only/) where the point was lying on the circle.Apparently, similar constructions cannot be made in this problem. [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/481019/straightedge-only-construction-of-a-perpendicular) discusses the case when the point lies outside the circle.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

If $UV$ and $WZ$ are two chords of $\Gamma$ through $X$, $UZ$ and $VW$ intersect on the polar line $l$ of $X$ wrt to $\Gamma$. The intersection $Y$ between $AB$ and $l$ is the inverse of $X$ with respect to $\Gamma$. If two lines through $Y$ meet $\Gamma$ at $D,E,F,G$, $DF\cap EG$ lies on the perpendicular to $AB$ through $X$.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this construct require that the polar line $l \perp AB$?

Comment: @Tebbe: since $X\in AB$ and $AB$ is a diameter of $\Gamma$, the polar line of $X$ is trivially perpendicular to $AB$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Does your method work if $X$ is outside the circle on the  extended diameter?

Comment: @Henry: it still works if $X\in AB$ but $X$ is not between $A$ and $B$. It has to be modified if $X$ is not on $AB$, but the argument through polars still gives a solution.

Comment: Anyway, if $X$ is not on $AB$, there is a simpler solution: draw $XA$ and $XB$, meeting $\Gamma$ at $C$ and $D$. $E=AD\cap BC$ is the orthocenter of $XAB$, hence $XE\perp AB$.

Answer (score 3):

The construction in the refereneced question allowes you as a side effect to reflect a point $P$ on the circle at the line $AB$ ($X\mapsto F$ with the illustration in the accepted answer).

Draw any line $\ne AB$ through $X$. Let it intersect the circle in $P$ and $Q$. Reflect $P$ at $AB$ to find $P'$. Let $AP'$ intersect $BQ$ in $C$. Then $CX\perp AB$.

Comment: It looks like this works in practice, but it deserves some kind of argument, doesn't it?

Comment: It works even if AB is not a diameter. It just requires an extra translation.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Of course. But the argument that $CX\perp AB$ i sthe same as for $C_1H\perp AB$ in the answer to the refernced question

Comment: @Hagen, I don't see it. It's clear to me why $C_1H$ is vertical in the previous question, but not how that argument would be modified/generalized to work here.

Comment: I can see that we could intersect $BP'$ and $AQ$ instead to meet in $C'$, and then $CC'$ would be vertical, by the orthocenter argument from the referenced question. But why does it pass through $X$?

Comment: It looks like this comes down to a claim that the altitudes in a triangle are angle bisectors in the triangle formed by their base points. Is this a well-known property?

Comment: @HenningMakholm: yes, it is.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Can you please explain in a little detail why $CX \perp AB$ ?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Also, does your method work if $X$ is outside the circle on the extended diameter?

Comment: @Henry I'll have to think about that with a real sketch before me - I just took the validity of the construction in the referenced answer for plausibly granted ...

Answer (score 2):

If anyone wants a proof here it is:

How to contruct that? My solution is:

From $X$ draw a random straightline, and then from $B$ and $C$ draw two lines which are concurrent with $l(X)$, being $l(X)$ the line passing throw $X$, they meet at $F$, choose a point $G$ on the line $XF$, let $CG$ intersect $FB$ at $E$ and $BG$ intersect $FC$ at $H$. Now let $L$ be the point were $EH$ intersect $BC$.

At point we have found the Pole of the $l(X)$. Proof: By construction $L,B,X,C$ are harmonic conjugates. And by one of the lemmas of pole, polar and the circle is that $(L,X;B,C)=-1$.

Now the Polar can be construct from the Pole using the Brokard's Theorem. From $L$ draw a line to the circle which intersect it at $K$ and $D$. Draw the complete quadrilateral $BKDC$ and its diagonals intersect at $I$ then $IX$ is the Polar.

Observation $L$ is inverse of $X$ respect the circle and conversly[image]

Comment: Does your method work if $X$ is outside the circle, on the extended diameter?